# SQL query of customers by area code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server database with customer information and need to run a query on the number of customers per area code. All phone numbers are U.S. phone numbers and stored as 10 digit numbers in a text field (no hyphens, parentheses or any other characters). I'm not a big whiz when it comes to writing SQL statements, so any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide the table structure for the table containing customer information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the first 3 digits in a phone number is the area code.

You can do something like

```
SELECT LEFT(PhoneNumber, 3) AS AreaCode
      ,COUNT(*) TotalNumberOfCustomer
FROM TableName
GROUP BY LEFT(PhoneNumber, 3)
```